# problem after upgrading perl

Tags: linux, spam, perl

I've upgraded perl which is install in /usr/local/lib/perl5/...... Previously old version of perl was installed in /usr/lib/perl5/

Now when i installed spamassasin its locating for the old location and show the following error.

Starting spamd: Can't locate Mail/SpamAssassin.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8 /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.3/i686-linux-thread-multi /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.3 /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.12.3/i686-linux-thread-multi /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.12.3) at /usr/bin/spamd line 84.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/spamd line 84.

I've tried changing shebang from /usr/bin/perl to /usr/local/bin/perl but it did not work.

"perl -V" output.

Summary of my perl5 (revision 5 version 12 subversion 3) configuration:

Platform:
    osname=linux, osvers=2.6.18-238.9.1.el5, archname=i686-linux-thread-multi
    uname='linux nexfilter 2.6.18-238.9.1.el5 #1 smp tue apr 12 18:10:56 edt 2011 i686 i686 i386 gnulinux '
    config_args='-Dusethreads -es'
    hint=recommended, useposix=true, d_sigaction=define
    useithreads=define, usemultiplicity=define
    useperlio=define, d_sfio=undef, uselargefiles=define, usesocks=undef
    use64bitint=undef, use64bitall=undef, uselongdouble=undef
    usemymalloc=n, bincompat5005=undef
  Compiler:
    cc='cc', ccflags ='-D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64',
    optimize='-O2',
    cppflags='-D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include'
    ccversion='', gccversion='4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-50)', gccosandvers=''
    intsize=4, longsize=4, ptrsize=4, doublesize=8, byteorder=1234
    d_longlong=define, longlongsize=8, d_longdbl=define, longdblsize=12
    ivtype='long', ivsize=4, nvtype='double', nvsize=8, Off_t='off_t', lseeksize=8
    alignbytes=4, prototype=define
  Linker and Libraries:
    ld='cc', ldflags =' -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib'
    libpth=/usr/local/lib /lib /usr/lib
    libs=-lnsl -lgdbm -ldb -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lpthread -lc
    perllibs=-lnsl -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lpthread -lc
    libc=/lib/libc-2.5.so, so=so, useshrplib=false, libperl=libperl.a
    gnulibc_version='2.5'
  Dynamic Linking:
    dlsrc=dl_dlopen.xs, dlext=so, d_dlsymun=undef, ccdlflags='-Wl,-E'
    cccdlflags='-fPIC', lddlflags='-shared -O2 -L/usr/local/lib -fstack-protector'

Characteristics of this binary (from libperl):
  Compile-time options: MULTIPLICITY PERL_DONT_CREATE_GVSV
                        PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT PERL_MALLOC_WRAP USE_ITHREADS
                        USE_LARGE_FILES USE_PERLIO USE_PERL_ATOF
                        USE_REENTRANT_API
  Built under linux
  Compiled at May 13 2011 03:43:35
  @INC:
    /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.3/i686-linux-thread-multi
    /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.3
    /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.12.3/i686-linux-thread-multi
    /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.12.3
    .

Comment: What does the commands "which perl"  and "perl -V" return? (please enter without the quotation signs)

Comment: This error is about missing perl module. You can try to locate the file `SpamAssassin.pm`. If you can't find it in the proper path, you can try re-install the module.

Comment: Khaled, I know that its due to missing perl module. It was working fine before up gradation of perl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick solution: make a symlink from the old directory to the new one. This will allow you to have possibly several versions of perl symlinked from /usr/local/whatever to /usr/lib/perl5.

Another solution: looks like you've recompiled perl and it chose the default prefix of /usr/local. You may try to recompile it once again, but with --prefix="/usr" given to configure script. This will put your perl into the place the rest of the system expects to find it.